# How to stop the swapping of list after two swap's of a number

Tags: python

Below is the bubble sort program, need to have 2 condition

1. Swap the number only twice
2. Find the total number of swaps

   ```
   nlist = [5,3,4]
   for passnum in range(len(nlist)-1,0,-1):
           for i in range(passnum):
               if nlist[i]>nlist[i+1]:
                   temp = nlist[i]
                   nlist[i] = nlist[i+1]
                   nlist[i+1] = temp
                   print(nlist)
   ```

   Out

   ```
   [3, 5, 4]
   [3, 4, 5]
   ```

   Total 2 swaps

if `arr = [5,4,3,1]` here 1 has to swap 3 times which out has to `print too many swaps` need to `break` the every number after 2 swaps

Comment: 1 only has to swap 3 times for the second example, not 4.

Comment: ok :) edited the ques

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why do you need this, but you can use `collections.Counter` for example.

```
from collections import Counter
cnt = Counter()
nlist = [5,3,4,1]
for passnum in range(len(nlist)-1, 0, -1):
    for i in range(passnum):
        if nlist[i] > nlist[i+1]:
            if cnt[nlist[i]] >= 2 or cnt[nlist[i + 1]] >= 2:
                continue
            nlist[i], nlist[i+1] = nlist[i+1], nlist[i]
            cnt += Counter({nlist[i]: 1, nlist[i + 1]: 1})
            print(nlist)
print('total swap count: {}'.format(sum(cnt.values())/2))
```